# Riak - why can't I go to http://localhost:8091/stats in my browser? (Seven Databases in Seven Weeks)

Tags: riak

I'm trying to work through the book [Seven Databases in Seven Weeks](http://pragprog.com/book/rwdata/seven-databases-in-seven-weeks), and I'm in the process of setting up Riak. After installing Riak, starting a few servers, and putting them together in a cluster, the book says to verify the servers are healthy by checking their stats by going to the address `http://localhost:8091/stats` in a web browser. However, when I go to this address in my web browser, I'm unable to connect.

The book is somewhat outdated so this could be something riak used to support but doesn't anymore -- but I don't know whether that's the case. It also may be relevant that I'm doing this within a, Oracle Virtualbox VM I've installed on my Windows 7 work laptop, running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that's not the port it runs on any more. You can have a look in the server's app.config (e.g. dev/dev1/etc/app.config), which is mentioned in the book in case you need to change the port.

On my instance it looks like it's running on port 10018, so I can see the stats on localhost:10018/stats (dev1), 10028 (dev2) and 10038 (dev3)

Comment: you'd think someone making a book like this would consider that Riak may change the default ports it uses